# React Shows Data in console but does not render it on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am super new to React and have just started my journey with it I have another page where I use the same function of handleIndexEmployees and the same const variables with useState and useEffect which load just fine. Right now with the code I have the only thing that shows up is

`<h1>Employees</h1>`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { EmployeesAxios } from "./EmployeesAxios";
export function EmployeesIndex() {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
  const handleIndexEmployees = () => {
    console.log("Wait I'm getting Da Minions");
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/employees.json").then((response) => {
      console.log("Hello my Minions");
      console.log(response.data);
      setEmployees(response.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(handleIndexEmployees, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <EmployeesAxios employee={employees} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export function EmployeesAxios(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Employees</h1>
      {props.employee.map((employee) => {
        <div key={employee.id}>
          <h3>Name: {` ${employee.first_name} ${employee.last_name}`}</h3>
        </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
 {props.todos.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo.id}>
          <h2>{todo.name}</h2>
          <p>{todo.description}</p>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              axios.patch(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${todo.id}.json`).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
              });
            }}
          >
            {todo.done}
            Done
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => props.onShowTodo(todo)}>More info</button>
        </div>
      ))}
```

I tried putting this all on one page with making all the requests on that page, and I get the same response with that so my page that I am rendering for a selector wheel to assign tasks to that employee works just fine with using props so that is why I tried moving all the axios requests to another page and passing in props. I also tried using isLoading as well and this didn't work either.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: `props.employee.map((employee) `
I think you should have different variable name in the loop? this should throw you the error

Comment: @sillyknight02 the map would create a new scope and the same variable name would not cause an error. `const employee = [1,2,3]` `employee.map(employee=>console.log(employee))` would work without issue but of course then you cannot access the initial array inside the map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning anything from your map.

Add a return statement here

```
{
  props.employee.map((employee) => {
    // Return something from the map
    return (
      <div key={employee.id}>
        <h3>Name: {` ${employee.first_name} ${employee.last_name}`}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan this fixed my problem. I am curious to why I don't declare return in my Task index map and that returns the data but on employees it does not. Again thank you very much!

Comment: If you can show your code for the task index map I could probably tell you. But your TaskIndex `map` probably looks something like this `something.map(e=>(<div>//stuff</div>))` . Arrow functions will automatically return if they are wrapped in `( ) parentheses`. `{} braces` will define a new code block and a code block needs a `return`

Comment: Yeah you nailed it right on the head with what I did different on my TaskIndex compared to my EmployeesIndex. Are using parentheses best practice?

Comment: It just depends on your case really. If you want to do additional data changes you can then treat each iteration as a function and do some logic in the braces then finally return what you want. If you're just straight up returning the data in JSX with minimal changes then parenthesis is fine. Could you mark the answer as accepted so we can close the original question :)